# Maximum databases on mysql server and security

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 9 databases on an MYSQL server right now. I configured them using the command line, adding a user and giving that user only full permissions to a specific database. The mysql server has 512MB ram right now, and i don't know if i should be worried security wise of any problems that might arise with 9 databases on one server. Should I split it up into two servers each with about 4 to 5 at most? I have 2 other app servers running to handle the load of the websites, but those 2 servers hit the database server for everything. So far, no problems. I have all 3 servers set with IP restrictions (iptables and other firewall), so hacking from elsewhere isn't possible, but only from the apps themselves. 
Since I created the users each with a restriction to a specific database, a hacker who hacks one can't get to the rest, i assume?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The mysql server has 512MB ram right now, and i don't know if i should
>   be worried security wise of any problems that might arise with 9
>   databases on one server.

Is the server cup running at 100% all the time?
Are there a lot of slow queries?
This could indicate that the server needs more resources.

You can also check the size of the InnoDB Buffer Usage. Increasing this is often a good way to relieve some pressure.

> I have 2 other app servers running to handle the load of the websites,
>   but those 2 servers hit the database server for everything. So far, no
>   problems. I have all 3 servers set with IP restrictions (iptables and
>   other firewall), so hacking from elsewhere isn't possible, but only
>   from the apps themselves

This is good. That way no one can access your db server directly only through the app servers.

> Since I created the users each with a restriction to a specific
>   database, a hacker who hacks one can't get to the rest, i assume?

Correct.

Comment: Most of the time, CPU usage is 99% idle with 1% being used, and at most sometimes 80% with 20% being used... I think performance wise, everything is fine. I just have several apps running with the 1 sql server so i just didn't know if I needed to split things up.

Comment: Until you notice a constant cpu usage then you don't need to split things.